# Number of products per page in jigoshop's shop

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, jigoshop

I am using [jigoshop for wordpress ecommerce](http://jigoshop.com/). I am going through a problem where I can see only 5 products per page in my [shop page](http://www.1kviews.com/shop/). I don't know what is wrong. Here's a screenshot of my shop page:

[image: www.1kviews.com shop]

Here you can see the `Next` pagination thing in the bottom of the page after 5 products. Where as, I have this configuration in the `jigoshop admin`:

[image: www.1kviews.com admin]

Here it says 5 page per column (which is working), but, 30 products per page, which isn't working. Is there any solution for this problem? Do I need to edit any code page for this?

Comment: Have you tried to contact the developer at Jigoshop? This isn't necessarily code problem that we can assist with and hence doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: On an unrelated note... are you selling views to Youtube videos? That's not cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself though.

```
<?php
global $columns, $per_page;

do_action('jigoshop_before_shop_loop');

$loop = 0;

if (!isset($columns) || !$columns) $columns = apply_filters('loop_shop_columns', 4);
//if (!isset($per_page) || !$per_page) $per_page = apply_filters('loop_shop_per_page', get_option('posts_per_page'));
//if ($per_page > get_option('posts_per_page')) query_posts( array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => $per_page ) ) );
```

This is the code what I had before in `templates/loop-shop.php`. I removed the two inline comments `//` and make it work. The final look of the code:

```
<?php
global $columns, $per_page;

do_action('jigoshop_before_shop_loop');

$loop = 0;

if (!isset($columns) || !$columns) $columns = apply_filters('loop_shop_columns', 4);
if (!isset($per_page) || !$per_page) $per_page = apply_filters('loop_shop_per_page', get_option('posts_per_page'));
if ($per_page > get_option('posts_per_page')) query_posts( array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'posts_per_page' => $per_page ) ) );
```

Cheers!